# How to fetch data in to custom wordpress table using wp_list_table

Tags: php, wordpress

[image]I am trying to create a custom table in wordpress using wp_list_table. I am trying to display the id , username and user mail. i have created the custom table as a plugin. My issue is the table have been created but am unable to fetch the data. Here is my code . and why is there 2 tables displaying. Please Help me

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Custom Tables 

*/
?>


<?php
if( ! class_exists( 'WP_List_Table' ) ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php' );




class My_List_Table extends WP_List_Table {

function getdata($user_id){

         $args= array(

            'user_id'   =>'ID',
            'role'      =>'',
            'orderby'   =>'login',
            'fields'    => 'ID','user_login','user_email');

         $data = get_users($args);

}

function get_columns(){
  $columns = array(
    'ID' => 'Case ID',
    'user_login'    => 'Patient Name',
    'user_email'      => 'Patient Email'
  );
  return $columns;
}

function prepare_items() {
  $columns = $this->get_columns();
  $hidden = array();
  $sortable = array();
  $this->_column_headers = array($columns, $hidden, $sortable);
  $this->items = $this->example_data;;
}

function column_default( $item, $column_name ) {
  switch( $column_name ) { 
    case 'ID':
    case 'user_login':
    case 'user_email':
      return $item[ $column_name ];
    default:
      return print_r( $item, true ) ; //Show the whole array for troubleshooting purposes
  }
}
}


// $myListTable = new My__List_Table();


function my_render_list_page(){
  $myListTable = new My_List_Table();
  echo '<div class="wrap"><h2>My List Table Test</h2>'; 
  $myListTable->prepare_items(); 
  $myListTable->display(); 
  echo '</div>'; 
}

function my_add_menu_items(){
    add_menu_page( 'My Plugin List Table', 'My List Table Example', 'activate_plugins', 'my_list_test', 'my_render_list_page' );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_add_menu_items' );

}
?>
```

Comment: Check it out this http://codingbin.com/display-custom-table-data-wordpress-admin/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [example](https://gist.github.com/paulund/7659452) you may like to follow. and also a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-list-table-example/) . Look into [this](https://gist.github.com/paulund/7659452#file-example-wp-list-table-php-L140) line it will give you a better idea, function table_data() prepares your data.

May be you would like to use it and modify . I have used it many times in my plugins. [List Table Example](https://github.com/Veraxus/wp-list-table-example/blob/master/list-table-example.php)

Comment: Thank You Fr Yur Reply. But am trying to get my data from database. So i actually want to fetch the data from the database

Comment: if I will get sometime after my office I will add an example from my implementation that may be helpful to you .